# I'm using rapid JSON to parse an object enemy for a C++ turn based rpg and am having some strange error's

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have some Json files representing enemies in a game that I am trying to access and and copy into C++ variables.

```
 {
    "Wolf": {
        "Type": 0,
        "ID": 0,
        "Level": 1,
        "Name": "Wolf",
        "Health": 100,
        "Strength": 20,
        "Speed": 35,
        "Exp": 20,
        "Defense": 30,
        "Sprite": "Assets/Wolf_Sprite.png",
        "Status": "Normal"
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant part of my code

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/filereadstream.h"

/******************************
* The Base Values of the enemy.
*******************************/

using namespace rapidjson;

class EnemyType
{

private:
    std::string Name;
    std::string FileName;
    int ID;
    int Level;  
    double expGiven;
    double Health;
    double Speed;
    double Strength;
    double Defense;

    Document Doc;

public: 
    EnemyType() 
    {   
        FILE* pFile = fopen("Assets/Enemy_List/0.json", "rb");
        char buffer[65536];
        FileReadStream is(pFile, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        Doc.ParseStream<0, UTF8<>, FileReadStream>(is);
        assert(Doc.IsObject());
        assert(Doc.HasMember("Type"));
        assert(Doc.HasMember("ID"));
        assert(Doc.HasMember("Level"));
        assert(Doc.HasMember("Name"));
        assert(Doc.HasMember("Health"));

        Health = Doc["Health"].GetDouble();

    }
```

The issue is the file itself open correct and passes the isObject assert, however anything past that will crash without failure... Any help would be appreciated.

From the Stack window   ucrtbased.dll!issue_debug_notification(const wchar_t * const message) Line 125  C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.

the error in the terminal: Assertion failed: Doc.HasMember("Type"), file c:\users\timothy\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\musungo game\musungo game\enemytype.h, line 36

edit: I found the answer was the .HasMember i was specifying the wrong word instead it should have been Doc.HasMember("Class")) instead

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger? At the very least post a stack trace.

Comment: I suppose Health is int and should be retried using GetInt try to assert the type of the element not only its presence assert(Doc["Health"].IsNumber());
assert(Doc["Health"].IsDouble());

Comment: @tambre Just edited my post

Comment: Well "Type" Is child of "Wolf", so it should be Doc["Wolf"].HasMember("Type")

Comment: That got me past the first set of asserts... But if I have to manually specify what parent it needs to look to I might need to rethink my design... Oh and can you post it as an answer so I can mark this question answered??

Comment: @user2350585 Is there really any design to be rethought? Just a temporary variable referencing or pointing to that child object. Also, please next time format the stack trace properly and post the **full** stack trace, not only the last line. They aren't very useful, if you can't see the full trace.

Comment: You should close pFile when finished...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
the error in the terminal: Assertion failed: Doc.HasMember("Type")
```

The reason for this error - Type is child of Wolf so it should be accesses as Doc["Wolf"]["Type"] and the assert should look like

```
assert(Doc.HasMember("Wolf"));
assert(Doc["Wolf"].HasMember("Type"));
```

Or with suggestion from user2350585

```
assert(Doc.HasMember("Wolf"));
auto Wolf = Doc["Wolf"];
assert(Wolf.HasMember("Type"));
```